# vs code wrap multiple line in quote

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to vscode and and hardly get bothered by one thing.

```js
var template = "<div>
                  <input type="text" class="input">  
                  <input type="text" class="input"> 
                  <input type="text" class="input">  
                  <input type="text" class="input"> 
                  <input type="text" class="input"> 
                </div> "
```

I have no clue why vscode is not wrapping all those line in quote. It just throws a syntax error. It reads when they aligned in one line but when I break the line to make it look good, the code is not working.
Any idea?

Comment: This question is not VSC nor `macos` specific. I assume you using `JS` to create those lines because of `var template` am I correct? JS doesn't create correct indentions when using `innerHTML` . The syntax error accures because those lines are not in a single line and as such are invalid for a `JS`-variable.

Comment: It also fails because you use double-quotes for the HTML attributes aswell as to open and close the varaible. Either the attributes or the var has to be opened and closed with single quotes instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```js
var template = `
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="input">  
    <input type="text" class="input"> 
    <input type="text" class="input">  
    <input type="text" class="input"> 
    <input type="text" class="input"> 
  </div>
`;
                    
document.body.innerHTML = template;
```

If you aren't familiar with template strings [here is the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: You might want to explain what you've done (and add some links to documentation) rather that make the OP guess.

Comment: It does work @tacoshy. I just checked it.

Comment: I updated tenhill's answer with the snippet you suggested. What isn't working? @tacoshy What errors are you getting?

Comment: @andy dont know if it was the linebreaks or something. It didnt parsed and outputted `unexpected token` for me. Maybe a caching error?

Comment: Even the line-breaks didn't matter. I just tidied up the code a little.

Comment: Good work @tenhill.

Comment: @Andy Thank you very much, it's my first voted answer.

Comment: No problem. Your answer is the correct one, but it just needed a little help. Hope you didn't mind me editing your answer a little bit to include that snippet (the `[<>]`) icon in the edit menu). Welcome to SO! @tenhill

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. Just use single quotes to surround the variable string, and use backslashes to change lines.

```js
var template = '<div>\
                  <input type="text" class="input"> \
                  <input type="text" class="input"> \
                  <input type="text" class="input"> \
                  <input type="text" class="input"> \
                  <input type="text" class="input"> \
                </div>';
                
document.body.innerHTML = template;
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because of multiple reasons:

1. You use double-quotes both to open and closing the variable aswell as the attributes. The opening double-quote of the first attribute already closes the variable therefor.
2. A JS variable is not allowed to have linebreaks.
3. you do not close the variable with a semicolon or comma (in case more variables follow)

The only way you can fix it is like in the example below. You have to open and close the variable and use a `+` to continue the variable in the next line:

```js
var template = '<div>' +
                 '<input type="text" class="input">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="input">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="input">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="input">' +
                 '<input type="text" class="input">' +
               '</div>';
            
document.body.innerHTML = template;
```

Comment: Generally the standard is that HTML attributes should be in double quotes, so I would swap those quotes around.

Comment: this is correct, but clumsy. Unnecessary concatenation as well as the use of single quotes in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

or you can

```js
var template = '<div>\
                  <input type="text" class="input">\
                  <input type="text" class="input">\
                  <input type="text" class="input">\
                  <input type="text" class="input">\
                  <input type="text" class="input">\
                </div>'
```